# What is the big sword saying in Super Mario RPG? (includes picture)

Tags: meaning, translation

Several pieces of what the giant sword says is confusing and I'm not able to gather enough information to make sense of it.

I'll include 2 pictures to help with context.

[image]

Here I think he's saying something like: "Smith King's desire is very easy to understand. That is, this world will be taken!"

[image]

Here is where I get confused. I'll separate into 3 lines. I think he is saying something like:

1. So then, where going also (I'm not sure what the も does here)
2. you act like a wannabe hero
3. uninvited come from...

Finally, the last thing he says after that sentence is just 1 thing before he shakes Mario away. He says "こうじゃい！" I don't know what the こう means because it has many definitions.

I feel like I'm not understanding something important with the sentence. How accurate is my translation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～ても means something like 'even if' or 'no matter'. Because the sentence pairs it within a question word, here we have 'no matter where one goes'.

おまえのような　ヒーローきどり is a whole noun phrase, ヒーローきどり itself being one noun. 'Wannabe heroes like you'.

しゃしゃりでる essentially means to butt into things that don't concern you. から directly following a predicate means 'because'.

'And, because wannabe heroes like you butt in no matter where we go...'

I believe こう here is simply 'like this' or 'this way'. じゃい has a similar meaning to だよ and is mainly used in fiction or certain dialects. 'This is what we'll do!'

Comment: This is very helpful. I understand 'NounのNoun', but I am not familiar with a "whole noun phrase" and I'm not seeing this when Googling. Do you happen to know of a good tutorial explaining this concept? Thank you!

Comment: @GrumpyBread A 'noun phrase', in any language, is a set of words together that grammatically acts as one noun. Nouns modified by adjectives or relative clauses form noun phrases, like 'green tree' or 'the cat that ate the fish'. In this case, we have 'wannabe heroes like you' being a noun phrase.

Comment: I understand, thank you!! I managed to find this site that has more about noun phrases and other helpful info for beginners I found very helpful.
https://8020japanese.com/japanese-sentence-structure/